# Python 3 - Example of Multithreading request using requests, asyncio and concurrent

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

So, I wrote the following code based on an example of a multi request using asyncio and concurrent libs, that I found [here](http://skipperkongen.dk/2016/09/09/easy-parallel-http-requests-with-python-and-asyncio/).

Basically, for a given list of names, I make some parallel requests to get the user's ID. (That's just an example of usage)

The values returned from getUserId function are stored in the 'futures' list, and you can get these values using the result() method that can be accessed from each element in the list.

This is currently a good approach?

```
import requests, asyncio, concurrent

async def makeMultiRequests(names):

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        futures = [
            loop.run_in_executor(
                executor, 
                getUserId, 
                name
            )
            for name in names
        ]

    return futures

def getUserId(username):
    # requests.get() user Id
    return userId;

names = ['Name 1', ..., 'Name N']

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
resultList = loop.run_until_complete(makeMultiRequests(names))
loop.close()

for result in resultList:
    print(result.result()) # Users Id printed
```

Best regards.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @dirn Edit: Asked for a good approach

Comment: A better approach is to use a library compatible with asyncio (e.g. [aiohttp](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/) instead of [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)) so you don't have to use a thread pool executor.

Comment: @Vincent can you explain why this is better and why thread pool executor is not compatible with asyncio?

Comment: The thread pool executor is what allows an asyncio program to communicate with non asyncio based libraries. However, by using this approach, you won't benefit from the advantages of single-thread asynchronous programming, which is the whole idea behind asyncio.

Comment: With your current approach, you can have a limited number (currently 20) of `getUserId` instances running in parallel - and that is good, because each instance corresponds to an OS thread. If `getUserId` were an `async def` that used an async http library, you could spawn literally thousands of them without noticeable impact on the system.

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate that